# how do I fix TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index?

Tags: python, numpy

When I was creating code to make it so that I enter a "Pin" and the code would try and decode it I made a code to solve this problem but it looped too many times so I tried shortening it with this.

```
import numpy as np

print('enter your pin')
p = [
[int(input())],
[int(input())],
[int(input())],
[int(input())]
]
x = [
[0],
[0],
[0],
[0]
]
np_X = np.array(x)
y = [
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1]
]
np_Y = np.array(y)

while np_X.all(np_X) != p:
        np_X = np_X + np_Y
        print(np_X)
```

but it gave me an `error` and i tried solving it on my own but all i got was

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop to this.

- np_X == p will return an array of boolean values.
- Each boolean value will correspond to whether the numbers in both array match.
- np.all will return true only if every element in an array is true
- Therefore, np.all(np_X == p) returns true if n_X is exactly p

```
while not np.all(np_X == p):
    np_X = np_X + np_Y
    print(np_X)
```

However, your entire code still wont work. You are adding 1 to **every element of x**. Instead, it seems you want to iterate over all possible combinations of 4 integers 0 - 9.

ie.

```
from itertools import combinations
for pin_1, pin_2, pin_3, pin_4 in combinations(range(9), 4):
    np_X = np.array([[pin_1], [pin_2], [pin_3], [pin_4]])
    if np.all(np_X == p):
        break
print(np_X)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np_X` is a (4,1) array:

```
In [114]: np_X                                                                  
Out[114]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

This is the code that generates the error.  You should have shown the whole traceback.  It helps us, and **you** identify where the problem occurs.

```
In [115]: np_X.all(np_X)                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-a3b876cb154f> in <module>
----> 1 np_X.all(np_X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     46 
     47 def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 48     return umr_all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     49 
     50 def _count_reduce_items(arr, axis):

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Look at the docs of `numpy` `all`.  It takes a `axis` parameter, not an array!

Valid uses are:

```
In [116]: np_X.all(0)                                                           
Out[116]: array([False])
In [117]: np_X.all(1)                                                           
Out[117]: array([False, False, False, False])
```

What are you trying to do?  Compare `p` with `np_X`?

```
In [119]: np_X != p                                                             
Out[119]: 
array([[ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True]])
```

Apply the `all` method to that boolean array:

```
In [120]: (np_X != p).all()                                                     
Out[120]: False
```

Making your arrays (4,1) shape, column vectors, is an unnecessary complication.  A simple 4 element array will be enough:

```
In [121]: np_X = np.zeros(4, int)                                               
In [122]: np_X                                                                  
Out[122]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
p = [
int(input()),
int(input()),
int(input()),
int(input())
]
```

or simply:

```
p = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`while np.all(np_X != p)`

you are printing

```
while np_X.all(np_X) != p:
```